# Two sets are equivalent if and only if they span the same vector space

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

The definition they gave me of equivalent sets is:

Two sets of vectors {$v_1,...,v_n$} , {$w_1,...,w_n$} are equivalents if every vector of each set can be written as a linear combination of the vectors of the other set.

Now they are asking me to prove that:

> 1. Two sets of vectors are equivalent $\iff$ they span the same vector space.
> 2. In $R^4$ give 2 examples of sets of equivalent vectors

Comment: OK, so what have you tried? Where did you get stuck?

Comment: @Noah Schweber I tried writing down a linear combination of both sets equal to generic vectors $v$ and $v_1$ , because to see they generate the same space a vector $v$ should be able to be written as a linear combination of the vectors of the first set and also of the vectors on the second one, I'm seeking how to put together something like that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I owe you the 2nd answer, This proof occurred to me seeing other proofs related to spanned sets, If you think there is something wrong with it, please tell me to check and if it's legit I'll delete my answer.

Thanks

[image]

[image]

Re-edit: The answer to the second question is: Find two basis for $R^4$ and the will be equivalent sets, this is because of the theorem (so to call it) proven before.

Answer (score 0):

If $v$ is in the span of $V = \{v_1,\ldots,v_n\}$ then you can write it as a linear combination of the elements of this set. But if $V$ is equivalent to another set $W$, you can write each element of $V$ as a linear combination of the elements of $W$. There's only one natural thing to do at that point, and the only difficult part is choosing notation that makes it easy to read.